# Caja / Google Apps Script & jQueryUI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-apps-script, jquery-ui-accordion, google-caja

This may prove to be an exceptionally naive problem to have as I'm just starting with jQueryUI, but better to ask a stupid question than go insane trying to figure out a bug which isn't mine.  Ultimately, I'm trying to generate a dynamic list of items which will be displayed to the user as a JQUI accordion - the problem is, it just never works.

My read of the documentation (including Google's that this should work in the Caja / GAS sandbox) is that this should result in 10 'rows' of accordion goodness.  In practice, though, only three convert to the accordion style while the remainder keep their original boring formatting.  Nothing appears in the console - no errors, warnings, etc.  The same HTML portion does, however, work purely client-side, hence my concern about a sandboxing / syntax issue.

Where am I going wrong?

Please see the below sample code from the Google Apps Script project:

code.gs:

```
function doGet()
{
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myHtml.html').evaluate();
}
```

myHtml.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <script>
      function createAccordion()
      {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        {
          html += "<h3><div>Heading " + i + "</div></h3><div>Body " + i + " </div>\n";
        }
        console.log(html);
        $("#accordion").html(html);
        $("#accordion").accordion();
      }      
      $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("Hello, world!");
        createAccordion();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accordion">Stuff</div>
    <p>Hello!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: Bizarre twist -- if I initialize the accordion like so:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
```

it inexplicably works just as would (otherwise) be expected.  My best guess is that this is something to do with Caja's parser sending back something funky when jQueryUI asks for all of "#accordion"'s children(), but which doesn't interfere with the .find() results.  I'm all eyes for more informed opinions, though!

Comment: Have you had a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285497/use-of-form-structure-inside-jquery-accordion-on-google-app-scripts  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466681/jquery-example-with-html-service/12469431#12469431

Comment: Thanks ScampMichael - I've seen both.  The first as I read it is a form structure in HTML issue which is not the case here, and the second a failure to place script tags in the appropriate location (body vs. head).  I *think* my question is to do with dynamic DOM & its interaction with jQueryUI, but that's why I'm looking for input as I don't see any relation to the other topics I've found.  Thanks!